# Google Meet Auto-close script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-chrome

Im trying Tampermonkey to close Google Meet ( or the browser, but the final objective is to leave the meeting), when it get "x" participants.

In the console it shows (roomates, null) I think it is just ruinning the code when the page starts, but I dont know how to loop it.

After the script be able to define the variable the number of participants I will try to do an If () and close page.

If there s any better ideas I would be grateful
The only thing I could get without errors was this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Sair Meet
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Get out classroom if "x" roomates in the room.
// @author       MTRD
// @match http://*/*
// @match https://meet.google.com//*
// @match https://meet.google.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var roomates = document.querySelector("#ow3 > div.T4LgNb > div > div:nth-child(4) > div.crqnQb > div.pHsCke > div.Jrb8ue > div > div.NzPR9b > div.uArJ5e.UQuaGc.kCyAyd.kW31ib.foXzLb.IeuGXd.M9Bg4d > span > span > div > div > span.wnPUne.N0PJ8e");

(function() {
    'use strict';
   console.log("roomates:" , roomates);


})();
```

Note: this document.querySelector, is the JS path that I got from the meet page, inspecting the element, it is the same for all meetings, just the string(roomates) that changes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Foaq3.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ivec.png

Answer (score 0):

To iterate a function, you need to use `setTimeout(<fxn>, <time in millisec>)`, as in the below code:

```
var t=null;
    function membersfunction() {
        console.log("checking members");
        //check for active members in meet
        if (document.querySelector(".gV3Svc>span").nextElementSibling.innerText < x) {
            console.log("STOP THE MEET");
            try {
                window.document.querySelector(".FbBiwc").click(); //click the endcall btn on meet
            } catch {
                console.log("ERROR");
            }
        }
        else {
            t = setTimeout(membersfunction, 5000); //here it ll call itself after 5 seconds
        }
    }
```

This will check for the number of present users in the Google Meet and, if the members present are less than the value 'x', then it will exit, else it will again check for members after 5 seconds.

You can also check my "Google Meet Auto Leave chrome extension" link: [Google Meet Auto Leave](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-meet-auto-leave/ijbcojchpkeeegcffccflenaooemfoee)